# Creating a C function without compiler generated prologue/epilogue & RET instruction?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

Consider this function:

```
void foo(){
    //do something
}
```

In assembly it would look something like this (not accurate):

```
push something

;do stuff

pop something
ret
```

But I don't want this generated code (*RET*, *PUSH*, *POP* ...). I just want a label to a block of code, so I have to return myself:

```
void bar(){
    //do something
    asm("iret") //i want to use this function as a ISR
}
```

and in assembly it would look something like this:

```
; do something
iret
```

without *PUSH*, *POP* or *RET*. Are there any pre-processor directives or keywords that would allow me to accomplish this?

I'm using *GCC*, and *NASM* under Windows and I am attempting to generate my own Interrupt Service Routines (ISR).

Comment: have you tried -  inline ?

Comment: gcc has the `naked` attribute for this on some architectures - not x86 AFAIK though.

Comment: Unless you're writing your own OS you have no need to write an ISR. Under Windows interrupts are handled by the OS which dispatches them to device drivers as necessary.

Comment: @RossRidge : His post history suggests it is likely OSdev related or at least I made that assumption he knew what he was doing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to accomplish. it seems like you want an interrupt handler that does the `iret` without other pushes and pops by default.

---

### GCC

Using *GCC* (without *NASM*) something like this is possible:

```
/* Make C extern declarations of the ISR entry points */    
extern void isr_test1(void);
extern void isr_test2(void);

/* Define a do nothing ISR stub */
__asm__(".global isr_test1\n"
        "isr_test1:\n\t"
        /* Other stuff here */
        "iret");    

/* Define an ISR stub that makes a call to a C function */
__asm__(".global isr_test2\n"
        "isr_test2:\n\t"
        "cld\n\t"                    /* Set direction flag forward for C functions */
        "pusha\n\t"                  /* Save all the registers */
        /* Other stuff here */
        "call isr_test2_handler\n\t"
        "popa\n\t"                   /* Restore all the registers */
        "iret");

void isr_test2_handler(void)
{
    return;
}
```

Basic `__asm__` statements in *GCC* can be placed outside of a function. We define labels for our Interrupt Service Routines (ISRs) and make them externally visible with `.globl` (You may not need global visibility but I show it anyway).

I create a couple of sample interrupt service routines. One that does nothing more than an `iret` and the other that makes a function call to a *C* handler. We save all the registers and restore them after. *C* functions require the direction flag be set forward so we need a [*CLD*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CLD.html) before calling the *C* function. This sample code works for 32-bit targets. 64-bit can be done by saving the registers individually rather than using [*PUSHA*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSHA:PUSHAD.html) and [*POPA*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/POPA:POPAD.html).

**Note**: If using ***GCC* on Windows** the function names **inside** the assembly blocks will likely need to be prepended with an `_` (underscore). It would look like:

```
/* Make C extern declarations of the ISR entry points */    
extern void isr_test1(void);
extern void isr_test2(void);

/* Define a do nothing ISR stub */
__asm__(".global _isr_test1\n"
        "_isr_test1:\n\t"
        /* Other stuff here */
        "iret");    

/* Define an ISR stub that makes a call to a C function */
__asm__(".global _isr_test2\n"
        "_isr_test2:\n\t"
        "cld\n\t"                    /* Set direction flag forward for C functions */
        "pusha\n\t"                  /* Save all the registers */
        /* Other stuff here */
        "call _isr_test2_handler\n\t"
        "popa\n\t"                   /* Restore all the registers */
        "iret");

void isr_test2_handler(void)
{
    return;
}
```

---

### MSVC/MSVC++

Microsoft's *C/C++* compilers support the [*naked*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21d5kd3a.aspx) attribute on functions. They describe this attribute as:

> The naked storage-class attribute is a Microsoft-specific extension to the C language. For functions declared with the naked storage-class attribute, the compiler generates code without prolog and epilog code. You can use this feature to write your own prolog/epilog code sequences using inline assembler code. Naked functions are particularly useful in writing virtual device drivers.

An example Interrupt Service Routine could be done like this:

```
__declspec(naked) int isr_test(void)
{
    /* Function body */
    __asm { iret };
}
```

You'll need to deal with the issues of saving and restoring registers, setting the direction flag yourself in a similar manner to the *GCC* example above.

---

### GCC 7.x+ introduced Interrupt Attribute on x86/x86-64 Targets

On GCC 7.0+ you can now use [`__attribute__((interrupt))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html) on functions. This attribute was only recently supported on x86 and x86-64 targets:

> interrupt
>
> Use this attribute to indicate that the specified function is an interrupt handler or an exception handler (depending on parameters passed to the function, explained further). The compiler generates function entry and exit sequences suitable for use in an interrupt handler when this attribute is present. The IRET instruction, instead of the RET instruction, is used to return from interrupt handlers. All registers, except for the EFLAGS register which is restored by the IRET instruction, are preserved by the compiler. Since GCC doesn’t preserve MPX, SSE, MMX nor x87 states, the GCC option -mgeneral-regs-only should be used to compile interrupt and exception handlers.

This method still has deficiencies. If you ever want your *C* code to access the contents of a register as they appeared at the time of the interrupt, there is currently no **reliable** way to do it with this mechanism. This would be handy if you were writing a software interrupt and needed access to the registers to determine what actions to take (ie: `int 0x80` on Linux). Another example would be to allow an interrupt to dump all the register contents to the display for debug purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I found a neat workaround:

Define the function in assembly but call a extern c function:

```
bits 32

global _bar
extern _foo

section .data

section .text

_bar:
    call _foo
    iret
```

in C:

```
void foo(){
    //do your stuff here
}

extern void bar();

//bar is now your "naked" function
```

compiled with nasm and gcc under windows

Comment: Are you compiling and assembling under Windows? Linux? Which _C_ Compiler are you using? GCC? MSVC? Clang etc?

Comment: @Michael Petch fixed it

Comment: @Michael Petch this was kinda meant as a "bare bone" or pseudo code just to illustrate how one would accomplish a task like this

Comment: I see you updated your question with GCC on Windows. Thanks, that is specific. I added the _GCC_ tag to the question. You don't even need NASM for this, it can be done entirely in _C_ with basic assembly statements.

Comment: Or more simply, you could write the interrupt handler in GAS syntax instead of NASM, in a `.S` file, and build that with gcc.  (With `-m32` if you want; `bits 32` and `.code32` don't change the object file format, they just let you put 32-bit machine code where it doesn't belong (e.g. a 64-bit object file), so don't use those directives.)

Comment: You can't safely call a C function from an interrupt handler without saving/restoring the call-clobbered registers.  (EAX, ECX, EDX in most 32-bit conventions.  And the FPU state unless you stop the compiler from using SSE/AVX and x87).  The general idea is right, but you'll corrupt the registers of whatever user-space code got interrupted, unless that's intentional for something that only handles software-interrupt `int 123` calls, not async interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want the syntax of having a function without having the C compiler do anything. You can do this by linking to your assembly function, (and then it will need to of course copy the correct things onto the stack).

Your assembly routines just need an entry point for the C compiler to call, for instance:

The assembly portion would contain the following header:

```
global my_function 
my_function:
push r1
push r2
; Code 
ret
```

corresponding to:

```
void  my_function ( int arg1, char arg2 );
```

Comment: yes like this but i dont want to code in assembly, thats my whole problem i could do it like this but then i have to code the function in assembly too but i dont want that.