# The cross-platform version of gcc ignore the attribute tag __attribute__((interrupt)) of my function

Tags: gcc, x86, attributes, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I downloaded the intel IA-64 and 32 book because I wanted to know more in depth about how a CPU works. So I read the book and started to code some stuff. I enabled the IDT and when I want to program an interrupt handler I have that code :

```
extern "C"  __attribute__((interrupt)) void test (void* ptr)
{

}

int main (void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile with `i686-elf-g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -c -m32 main.cpp` I have the following warning : `main.cpp:6:60: warning: 'interrupt' attribute directive ignored`, but when I compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -c -m32 main.cpp` the compilation just works well and the code generated is like it should be with the iret instruction at the end (and that's what I want) :

```
Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:
_test:
       0:       55      push    ebp
       1:       89 e5   mov     ebp, esp
       3:       fc      cld
       4:       5d      pop     ebp
       5:       cf      iretd
       6:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00   nop     word ptr cs:[eax + eax]
```

Does anyone have any idea of why I have this warning with my cross platform version of gcc ? (and I am also wondering why an interrupt handler must have a pointer at parameter for gcc)

Comment: Are you on Windows with your "regular" `g++` set up to build Windows object files?  I was confused at first because you don't need a special `i686` version of gcc to make 32-bit x86 code.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am on macOS and my g++ is clang++ 9.0.0. To tell the truth, when I started I had no idea of what I was doing, so I just followed the tutoriel on OSDev [link](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler#OS_X_Users) . But I guess that if I doesn't set a prefix value to null gcc set its value to the targeted architecture (and in my case it was i686- and the elf is because of the tutoriel but maybe I don't need that)

Comment: @PeterCordes : I assumed from the question (using interrupt directive) that h'es doing OS development and using a cross compiler (which is recommended on OSDev wiki since the old days some distros use to tie/patch libgcc to use some host OS features). As well, on OS/X _LD_ doesn't support many of the options needed (like linker scripts) that allow you to OS Dev (So GNU Binutils is also much handier).

Comment: @MichaelPetch you're right even if I wouldn't have the pretension of saying that I am developing an OS ^^ I am just trying to put the CPU in a usable mode, but I will be pretty happy if this little project could ends up in an nice working OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `interrupt` attribute is only a recent addition to *G++* when targeting x86/x86-64 architectures and is available in *G++* 7.0 and later.I would guess that your `i686-elf-g++` cross compiler is earlier than 7.0 and your host compiler `g++` is 7.0 or later. You'll have to upgrade your i686 cross compiler to a newer version.

Comment: Really ? My regular version of g++ is clang++ 9.0.0 (I am on macOS) and my i686-elf-g++ version is 6.3.0. I founded the interrupt attribute when searching in the 6.3.0 documentation of g++ it is a little bit weird to document a feature that is not present oO

Comment: Apple's Clang/LLVM seems to have only supported the `interrupt` attribute since version 9 when targeting x86/x86-64. It has supported the interrupt attribute on functions for other targets like ARM and MIPS for much longer.

Comment: @Adrien : GCC and CLANG are different projects. And Apple has its own version of CLANG/LLVM with later XCode releases. The `interrupt` attribute has been around a while but only properly implemented for architectures like ARM and MIPS. It has been only more recently in GCC/CLANG/Apple CLANG(since about 2016). for the x86 and x86-64 platforms.

Comment: Older versions would ignore the `interrupt` attribute and usually throw a warning on unsupported platforms and it would be ignored.

Comment: Thanks it works well with gcc 7+, but I remember an advice saying that I should not use the last release but a one a little bit older because the newest are not tested enough, so maybe I should find another way to program interrupt handler in C/C++ ?

Comment: @Adrien 7.20 I think is the latest (7.2 is a bugfix release). Version 8 is being worked on now as the bleeding edge. GCC's of about 4.8.5 have been used extensively in Linux distros for both Userland and OS so it is probably a safe bet (It is the last of the 4.x series). There is no other way to do it unless you use inline assembly. An example of that for 32-bit you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311525/3857942 . Usually it is easiest to put the interrupt handler in an assembly file and make it call over into a _C_ function.