# Interrupt handler on C doesn't work after one interrupt

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, interrupt-handling, osdev

I'm trying to implement keyboard interrupt handler using C and QEMU. But when I execute the program my handler print only one character. After that the handler doesn't work at all.

My IDT setup:

```
struct IDT_entry {
    unsigned short int offset_lowerbits;
    unsigned short int selector;
    unsigned char zero;
    unsigned char type_attr;
    unsigned short int offset_higherbits;
};

void setup_idt() {
    struct IDT_entry IDT[256];
    unsigned long keyboard_address;
    unsigned long idt_address;
    unsigned long idt_ptr[2];

    keyboard_address = (unsigned long) keyboard_handler;
    IDT[0x21].offset_lowerbits = keyboard_address & 0xffff;
    IDT[0x21].selector = 0x8;
    IDT[0x21].zero = 0;
    IDT[0x21].type_attr = 0x8e;
    IDT[0x21].offset_higherbits = (keyboard_address & 0xffff0000) >> 16;

    /*
                PIC1   PIC2
    Commands    0x20   0xA0
    Data        0x21   0xA1

    */

    // ICW1 - init
    outb(0x20, 0x11);
    outb(0xA0, 0x11);

    // ICW2 - reset offset address if IDT
    // first 32 interrpts are reserved
    outb(0x21, 0x20);
    outb(0xA1, 0x28);

    // ICW3 - setup cascading
    outb(0x21, 0b0);
    outb(0xA1, 0b0);

    // ICW4 - env info
    outb(0x21, 0b00000011);
    outb(0xA1, 0b00000011);
    // init finished

    // disable IRQs except IRQ1
    outb(0x21, 0xFD);
    outb(0xA1, 0xff);

    idt_address = (unsigned long)IDT;
    idt_ptr[0] = (sizeof (struct IDT_entry) * 256) + ((idt_address & 0xffff) << 16);
    idt_ptr[1] = idt_address >> 16;

    __asm__ __volatile__("lidt %0" :: "m" (*idt_ptr));
    __asm__ __volatile__("sti");
}
```

My keyboard handler:

```
// Variables for printing ==
unsigned int location = 0;
char* vga = (char*)0xb8000;
char letter;
// =========================

void keyboard_handler() {
    if (inb(0x64) & 0x01 && (letter = inb(0x60)) > 0) {
        vga[location] = keyboard_map[letter];
        vga[location+1] = 0x4;
        location += 2;
    }

    outb(0x20, 0x20);

    // __asm__ __volatile__("iret");
}
```

Main function (it is executed from my asm bootloader):

```
void kmain() {
    setup_idt();

    for (;;) {}
}
```

I think the problem is in "iret" instruction. Without it my kernel prints at least something (only one charachter, like I said before). But when I execute **asm** **volatile**("iret");  QEMU prints some garbage and then clear it after every keystroke ("SeaBios ..."). What do I have to do?
Thank you!

Comment: Write a wrapper in pure assembly that calls your handler according to the C calling convention.

Comment: @Jester, what's the difference?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/jj203546(v=msdn.10)

Comment: Not related to your problem, but a change to the interrupt handler - `inb(0x64) & 0x01` isn't necessary to check from an interrupt handler. You only need to do that outside an interrupt handler where you are polling the keyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you compile without optimization, `asm("iret")` will probably run while the stack pointer is still pointing at a saved EBP value,  because `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is the default and the cleanup epilogue happens *after* the last C statement of the function.

Or it could be pointing at other saved registers.  Anyway, **tricking the compiler and jumping out of an inline asm statement is never going to be safe** (unless you use `asm goto` to maybe jump to a C label inside the function, but that doesn't solve your problem).

---

Also, **the C calling convention allows functions to clobber EAX, ECX, EDX, and the FPU state**.  Even if you did manage to hack an `iret` into your function, it would corrupt the state of the code that was interrupted.  GCC will use SSE/x87 to implement `_Atomic int64_t` load/store in 32-bit mode, and for copying large objects, unless you **compile with `-mgeneral-regs-only`**

Also see @MichaelPetch's answer on the linked duplicate: [Creating a C function without compiler generated prologue/epilogue & RET instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310704/creating-a-c-function-without-compiler-generated-prologue-epilogue-ret-instruc) for more interesting points, and some non-GCC info.

---

There are 2 solutions here:

- write a pure-asm wrapper that saves the call-clobbered regs, calls your C function, then returns with `iret`
- **declare your function with `__attribute__((interrupt))` to tell GCC it's an interrupt handler**.  The gcc manual's **[x86 function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html#index-interrupt-function-attribute_002c-x86) has an example**.

  x86 support for that attribute is somewhat recent compared to traditionally-embedded ISAs like ARM, but modern GCC does know how emit functions that preserve all regs and end with `iret`.  But you still need `-mgeneral-regs-only`.

See also https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Service_Routines#GCC_.2F_G.2B.2B which tells you the same thing as this answer.

(It also suggests an evil hack with `pushad` / `popad; leave; iret` which only works with optimzation disabled.  I would *not* recommend that if you can possibly use a newer GCC that supports the `interrupt` attribute.)

The earlier parts of the wiki page cover the general problems with trying to use your own `iret`, so you can see what the total asm (compiler-generated + yours) would look like for your attempt.